# The file not exist exception in Java

Tags: java, spring, file, upload

I try to upload file from web, and the file are stored in the file system.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/upload", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public @ResponseBody String handleFileUpload(
        @RequestParam("name") String name,
        @RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file) {
    if (!file.isEmpty()) {
        try {
            byte[] bytes = file.getBytes();
            File file1 = new File(name + ".upload");
            BufferedOutputStream stream = new BufferedOutputStream(
                    new FileOutputStream(file1));

            stream.write(bytes);
            stream.close();
            return "You successfully uploaded " + name + " into " + name
                    + "-uploaded !";
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return "You failed to upload " + name + " => " + e.getMessage();
        }
    } else {
        return "You failed to upload " + name
                + " because the file was empty.";
    }
}
```

the above code work well. But when I try to use absolute directory, it fail, the code like

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/upload", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public @ResponseBody String handleFileUpload(
        @RequestParam("name") String name,
        @RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file) {
    if (!file.isEmpty()) {
        try {
            byte[] bytes = file.getBytes();
            File file1 = new File("c:/" + name + ".uploaded");
            file1.getParentFile().mkdirs();
            BufferedOutputStream stream = new BufferedOutputStream(
                    new FileOutputStream(file1));

            stream.write(bytes);
            stream.close();
            return "You successfully uploaded " + name + " into " + name
                    + "-uploaded !";
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return "You failed to upload " + name + " => " + e.getMessage();
        }
    } else {
        return "You failed to upload " + name
                + " because the file was empty.";
    }
}
```

It throw file not exists exception, and I have already create dirs. Does someone know the reason? Thanks!

Comment: The problem is that there's no physical file in `"c:/" + name + ".uploaded"`, so `file1.getParentFile()` doesn't exist.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza shouldn't it be an NPE on mkDirs? [getParentFile](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#getParentFile())

Comment: No. It doesn't throw 'file not exists exception'. There is no such exception. Don't be sloppy about things like this. It probably throws `FileNotFoundException,` but you need to confirm that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your code block to the following

```
  @RequestMapping(value = "/upload", method = RequestMethod.POST)
  public @ResponseBody String handleFileUpload(
          @RequestParam("name") String name,
          @RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file) {

            String yourUploadDirectory = "uploads";


      if (!file.isEmpty()) {
          try {
              byte[] bytes = file.getBytes();
              File file1 = new File("c:/" + yourUploadDirectory + "/" + name + ".uploaded");

              // You must write this line so that the designated file is first created, otherwise getParentFile() will throw error.
              file1.createNewFile();

              file1.getParentFile().mkdirs();
              BufferedOutputStream stream = new BufferedOutputStream(
                      new FileOutputStream(file1));

              stream.write(bytes);
              stream.close();
              return "You successfully uploaded " + name + " into " + name
                      + "-uploaded !";
          } catch (Exception e) {
              e.printStackTrace();
              return "You failed to upload " + name + " => " + e.getMessage();
          }
      } else {
          return "You failed to upload " + name
                  + " because the file was empty.";
      }
  }
```

It is always good to have a dedicated folder for uploads..

Comment: It would be better using `File file1 = new File(yourUploadDirectory, name + ".uploaded");`. In this way, `yourUploadDirectory` could contain a value based on the OS the application is deployed.

Comment: I have tested it, it seems need first create the directory, then create the file, then it can work.

Comment: It will.. However, if the parent directory, that is uploads doesn't exists, it will automatically create it. And if can't, then probably you don't have appropriate permissions in that folder.